# How do you detect if a user creates a worksheet using ctrl-click in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way in Excel VBA to detect when a user creates a worksheet by holding ctrl and clicking on a tab then dragging it?

The `newsheet` event doesn't appear to be triggered when this occurs so was wondering if there is any other way to detect this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I know how to get around the problem is to keep track of the sheet count.

You can do this by adding a public variable to a module, e.g.

```
Public SheetCount As Integer
```

And then add the following event handlers into ThisWorkbook

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim newCount As Integer
    newCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    If newCount > SheetCount Then
        SheetCount = newCount
        MsgBox "sheet added"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)
    SheetCount = SheetCount - 1
End Sub
```

The MsgBox is just for testing purposes, naturally.